# Problem with elasticdump installation. Failed dependencies

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, npm

I'm trying to install elasticdump on my machine, but unfortunately I have a problem. I installed npm using binary file from here [enter link description here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/) I can check the version of npm (using npm -v) : 6.4.1 and node: v10.15.1 so i think everything is ok. When i want to install elastic dump using this command:

```
rpm -Uvh elasticdump-2.2.0-2.el7.noarch.rpm
```

I have this error

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    /usr/bin/node is needed by elasticdump-2.2.0-2.el7.noarch
    nodejs(engine) >= 1.0.0 is needed by elasticdump-2.2.0-2.el7.noarch
    npm(JSONStream) is needed by elasticdump-2.2.0-2.el7.noarch
    npm(async) < 2 is needed by elasticdump-2.2.0-2.el7.noarch
    npm(optimist) is needed by elasticdump-2.2.0-2.el7.noarch
    npm(request) >= 2 is needed by elasticdump-2.2.0-2.el7.noarch
    npm(request) < 3 is needed by elasticdump-2.2.0-2.el7.noarch
```

What should i do? I have to add that I don't have access to the internet from this machine. I can only install packages from files

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not simply installing with `npm install -g elasticdump`?

Comment: Error too." rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session xxxxxxxxxxx "   probably because no internet connection ?